# custom cell not appear in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I use storyboards. I create new class for my Cell, in storyboard I write in Reuse Identifier "userFullCell". My Cell class .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UsefullLinksCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *shortTitle;

@end
```

.m default

```
#import "UsefullLinksCell.h"

@implementation UsefullLinksCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
  self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

property **image** and **shortTitle** connected in storyboard with UILabel and UIImageView in Cell

Then in my class with UITableView I import "UseFullLinksCell.h" and in viewDidLoad wrote:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UsefullLinksCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"userFullCell"];
```

tableView is my outlet:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

and then I try to create cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"userFullCell";
  UsefullLinksCell *cell = (UsefullLinksCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  NSDictionary *info = resourceArray[indexPath.row];
  if(info){
    cell.image.image = info[@"logo"];
    cell.shortTitle.text = info[@"title"];
  }
  return cell;
}
```

So, cell initialize, but image and text not assigned, and after going end of method return 0x0000000 for cell. If I create for standart cell code in this method, I mean UITableViewCell *cell, there is all good. Where I could make mistake?
PS Sorry I can not give screenshots from storyboard, because I write from not my computer, if you want, I provide images later

Comment: What is resourceArray and where are you initializing the cell ?

Comment: resourceArray - array with dictionaries, with my information. It is work correctly for standart cell. I need initialize like wrote V-Xtreme? I need create xib? I use storyboard, so I need recreate with xib file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should register the xib file (with registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:) where you made your custom cell, not the class. Also, I don't know if this will make a difference or not, but replace this:

```
UsefullLinksCell *cell = (UsefullLinksCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

With this (notice the forIndexPath: at the end of the method):

```
UsefullLinksCell *cell = (UsefullLinksCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

**After Edit:**

If added a custom cell to your table view in the storyboard, and gave it the identifier "userFullCell", then you don't need to register anything -- in fact, registering your class makes it not work. So, just comment out that register statement, and see if that works.

Comment: I try to replace but it was not result. About xib file I asked in other answer, read please

Comment: @Neznajka, where in a storyboard did you create this cell? Is it added to a table view, and you modified it there?

Comment: @Neznajka, If you made the cell in the storyboard, try what I say in the edit to my answer.

Comment: yeah, I add UITableViewCell on my UItableView in storyboard; add Label, ImageView to it; write "userFullCell" in the identifier field in IB. You mean, I can delete method registerClass: forCellReuseIdentifier: ?

Comment: @Neznajka, yes, you can delete it.

Comment: Thanks, i was busting my head with this. Removing the registerClass method worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed something:

```
  NSArray *objects=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"UsefullLinksCell" owner:self options:nil];
 UsefullLinksCell *cell =[objects objectAtIndex:0];
```

this will give you the object of your custom cell.

Comment: I created in storyboard, I have not xib =( Or i am wrong, and not understand something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do the following

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
     self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
     if (self) {
      // Initialization code

          image=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50.0,50.0)];
          shortTitle=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0,0.0,200.0,50.0)];
     }
     return self;
}
```

Else all should work.. The thing is your components are not initialized anywhere, either it should be loaded from xib or, you have to initialize them manually.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I try this check later in evening.